# Understanding definition of an Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

The above is the definition of "Euclidean domain" written in Dummit and Foote, abstract algebra.

> I don't understand why a "Norm" is enough, it seems to me that we require a positive norm. What will happen if $b\ne 0$ but $N(b)=0$, won't that break the definition because $N(r)$ is non-negative? In that case how will we define $N(r)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the definition of a Euclidean domain see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain).

There is also a definition of a norm $N$ on an integral domain $D$, namely a function $N:D\rightarrow \mathbb Z$ that satisfies the following properties: $N(a)=0$ if and only if $a=0$ and $N(a)N(b)= N(ab)$.
This need not be positive. For example, $D=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ has norm $N(a+b\sqrt{2})=a^2-2b^2$, which can be negative. So units in $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ can have norm $+1$ or $-1$, see
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928494/units-in-mathbb-z-sqrt2).

On the other hand $N(b)=0$ can only happen for $b=0$, which solves your problem - see also [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjaw57Dz87nAhXBmFwKHU6nAfMQFjACegQIBRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.uchicago.edu%2F~lekheng%2Fcourses%2F114s09%2Fmath114s09-hw3sol.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1kBqISH5cPcgA4stuJfsFT).

Reference:

[Euclidean domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192449/euclidean-domain-mathbbz-sqrtd)

[Norms on general integral domains.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354169/norms-on-general-integral-domains)

Comment: How is this a norm? as $N(1+\sqrt{2}) = 1-2 = -1$, but $N:R \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$

Comment: Don't you mean $|a^2-2b^2|$ ??